# Writing to a database from a chrome extension

Tags: php, javascript, database, google-chrome-extension

This might be a broad question but I couldn't find a definite explanation on how to do this (maybe I am just not searching well enough).

I am writing a chrome extension which I need to write data I collect from a site to a database.

Problem is that I really have no idea how to do this or where to start. As mentioned in my previous posts it's my first google extension, and on top of that it is my first time I ever use a database. A lot of firsts in this project :).

After googling, I found out that I probably need to use php to do that since javascript is a client-side language. But other than that, I am completely stumped and don't really know how to begin.

Any tips please?

Again, sorry if my question is too broad. Maybe this topic will help a future newbies (like me) get up to speed with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens to the data you want to store? Is it purely for use by the client? or will it get processed once in the database or accessed by other clients later on? If it is purely for use by the local client then javascript, and localstorage will be fine. Otherwise, yes you will need a seperate database server to send the results to.

Comment: It will be accessed by other clients. So yea, I don't think I can do it locally. Thanks for replying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this article about how to make requests to a server from an extension: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Than, take a quick tutorial on how to create a simple php script that connects to a database. Maybe something like this: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: After some reading around (correct me if I am wrong about this). I need to send my data to a php script, then after which send it from that php script to the DB.
Is that correct?

Comment: yes, you can say that. But actually maybe it's misleading to say "send to the database", because the database and the php script will probably run on the same machine. Let's just say the php script takes care of saving the data to the database.